# ASP.NET MVC and Instagram RealTime API updates

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, instagram

I'm going to use Instagram real time api to subscribe to images with a specific tag. The API seems simple enough, but one thing bugs me.

> Also, you should acknowledge the POST within a 2 second timeout--if
>   you need to do more processing of the received information, you can do
>   so in an asynchronous task.

What would be the best way to just respond to Instagram as the request comes in, but still in the same action fetch the actual image from Instagram and create a new document in my database?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.

Edit:
Would a simple Response.Flush() in the beginning of the action be enough?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4.5, you can use the `async` and `await` keywords to process the return first, then wait for the image download. [See this article from Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).